# 'Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: habitat

I have installed **Sitecore Habitat V1.8.1** while run Default in Task run Explorer faced  below issue.

[image]

```
Error : 'Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Operable program or batch file.

If(err !=null) thorw err; in the file unicorn.js:44 file
```

[image]

Updated : Installed Powershell Version is 5.1 on my machine.

Comment: check the installed powershell version and Sitecore Habitat compatible powershell version.. These should match.

Comment: Installed poweshell version is 5.1.but i don't know how to check Sitecore Habitat compatiable powershell version ?

Comment: can you check your environment variables? make sure you have `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ` value in `Path` environment variable.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat path is already configured in environment variable

Comment: @Jitendra How can i check the powershell version in Sitecore habitat solution

Comment: Sitecore Habitat would be compatible with one of the Sitecore version.. Than see the which version of Powershell is compatible with the installed Sitecore version...

Comment: I download Sitecore Habitat version 1.8.1 from github. Curretly i installed sitcore 9.3 instance.Habitat is supported 9.2version sitecore . I updated all the reference pacakge from 9.2 to 9.3